# find records where field type is string

Tags: string, mongodb, field

I have this records :

```
{id : 1 , price : 5}
{id : 2 , price : "6"}
{id : 3 , price : 13}
{id : 4 , price : "75"}
```

I want to build a query that get just record who have price with type "string"

so, it will get :

```
{id : 2 , price : "6"}
{id : 4 , price : "75"}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the [`$type`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/#op._S_type) query operator to do this:

```
db.test.find({price: {$type: 2}})
```

If you're using MongoDB 3.2+, you can also use the string alias for the type:

```
db.test.find({price: {$type: 'string'}})
```

Answer (score 5):

While @JohnnyHK's answer is absolutely correct in most cases, MongoDB also returns documents where `field` is an array and any of the elements in that array have that type ([docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/type/#querying-by-data-type)). So for example, the document

```
{ 
  _id: 1,
  tags: ['123']
}
```

is returned for the query `Books.find({ tags: { $type: "string" } })` as well. To prevent this, you can adjust the query to be

```
Books.find({
  tags: {
    $type: "string",
    $not: {
      $type: "array"
    }
  }
})
```